# Vagrant - Unable to sync folder from secondary drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Whenever I run `vagrant up`, I get the same error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'www' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: /d/project
```

And here is the relevant setup in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "D:\\cq", "/var/www/project",
    owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```

My directory setup is a bit weird, so maybe the issue lies there. I'll list out anything I can think of that might be causing `vagrant up` to fail.

- My project lives in the `D:\` drive (not the primary `C:\` drive).
- Source directory (java project) is contained within target directory. I want to sync the target dir (including the sub-dir source)
- Host machine is Win7, box is `ubuntu/trusty64` per [this article](http://24ways.org/2014/what-is-vagrant-and-why-should-i-care/)

I'm just getting started with Vagrant, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but my research isn't turning up anything too useful. I've tried adding...

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
end
```

...per https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/183, but to no avail. If there is anything else I can provide to help troubleshoot this issue, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I replicate your error and it seems to be related to the string formatting. In Windows the vagrant file that I use is like this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "d:/tmp", "/var/www/html"
```

Try to changing the path to forward slash and use only one. Also I noted that the error message looks into */d/project* which I should understand is *D:\project*. That folder needs to exist in your drive.

Comment: I've chancged the formatting, but am still seeing the error. When you say that `/d/project` needs to exist in my drive, do you mean on my host machine or the VM? On my host machine, I have `D:/project` (which, in Cygwin gets printed `/d/project`). In my `provision.sh` file, I added `mkdir /d/project` to establish an existing path on the VM, but that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Mmm that is weird. The path "D:/project" is in the host machine. I haven’t installed Cygwin in my machine I don’t know if this is something that maybe is working against your setup... I also downloaded the same files used in the 24ways.org tutorial and the setup works perfectly. I can’t confirm that Cygwin is causing some conflict but it is variable that I don’t have here. Other thing could be a security permission in the "D:/project" path.